# WPF command parameter for MiddleClick on CheckBox in ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, itemscontrol

I want to trigger a command when I use a MiddleClick on a Checkbox in an `ItemsControl`. I need to return the item source as a command parameter. I have tried two methods in XAML.

Method 1:

```xml
<ItemsControl x:Name="CheckBoxItems" ItemsSource="{Binding Curves}" Grid.Row="1">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Gesture="MiddleClick" Command="{Binding SelectOnlyCommand}"
                      CommandParameter="{Binding }"/>
    </ItemsControl.InputBindings>
</ItemsControl>
```

This method returns the UserControl to the command instead of the item source.

Method 2:

```xml
<ItemsControl x:Name="CheckBoxItems" ItemsSource="{Binding Curves}" Grid.Row="1">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Margin="0,0,5,0">
                <CheckBox.InputBindings>
                    <MouseBinding Gesture="MiddleClick" Command="{Binding Path=SelectOnlyCommand}"
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding }"/>
                </CheckBox.InputBindings>
            </CheckBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    
</ItemsControl>
```

This method does not trigger the SelectOnlyCommand. Thanks for your help.

Comment: So you just want to have the `Curves` passed as parameter? Because for that you can just simply write `CommandParameter="{Binding Curves}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Edited)
if you want to pass the single item, it works like this:

```
 <ItemsControl x:Name="CheckBoxItems" ItemsSource="{Binding Curves}" Grid.Row="1">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Margin="0,0,5,0">
                        <CheckBox.InputBindings>
                            <MouseBinding Gesture="MiddleClick" Command="{Binding ElementName=CheckBoxItems, Path=DataContext.SelectOnlyCommand}"
                                          CommandParameter="{Binding }"/>
                        </CheckBox.InputBindings>
                    </CheckBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>                
        </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: VS1 and vs2 return the full collection, instead of the single source.

Comment: Are you sure he wants the single item? I read it as if he wanted the whole collection aka "ItemsSource"

Comment: @spainchaud Sorry, you're the one that asked, lol....
See my new version and also the one of YoChauhan that use ElementName...to link to the "outer" DataContext

Comment: Work perfect now. Thanks. My users want a middleclick to turn off all checkboxes except the one clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with way 2 , but problem is you not able to bind Command. You will have to bind it by ElementName.

```
  <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Margin="0,0,5,0">
                        <CheckBox.InputBindings>
                            <MouseBinding Gesture="MiddleClick" Command="{Binding ElementName=CheckBoxItems, Path = DataContext.SelectOnlyCommand}"
                                          CommandParameter="{Binding }"/>
                        </CheckBox.InputBindings>
                    </CheckBox>
```

Comment: He can also use his CheckBox "CheckBoxItems" as ElementName, its DataContext has that SelectOnlyCommand